# Is "find all extreme values" the same as finding all the critical points?

Tags: functions, partial-derivative

The instructions state to "find *all* extreme values and their type" for the function $f(x, y) = xy(5x + y - 15)$. So I went through the steps using partial derivatives, and the resulting critical points are $(0, 0)$, $(3, 0)$, $(0, 15)$ and $(1, 5)$. But when I re-read the question, am I even answering it correctly or am I incorrectly assuming that finding all extreme values refers to finding all the critical points?

If I go to Wolfram Alpha and type in `extrema xy(5x + y - 15)`, the result it gives is `"Local Minimum": min{x y (5 x + y - 15)} = -25 at (x, y) = (1, 5)`.

So in other words, it only shows one of the critical points that I found when I use the command extrema. But my example definitely asks for all extreme values, so now I'm just confused about what the question wants. When the question says "find their type", I'm guessing they mean whether it is a local minimum, maximum etc? Thanks for your ideas.

Comment: A critical point could also be a saddle point; in that case it is not an extreme value.

Comment: Since your  $f$ is differentiable all extreme values are critical points, but a critical point is not necessarily an extreme value (see saddle points).

Answer (score 1):

The critical points of a differentiable function $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ are all points with vanishing gradient, while extreme points only include local maxima and local minima.

For example the map $\mathbb R^1\to\mathbb R$ given by $x\mapsto x^3$ has a critical point at $x=0$ that does not yield a local maximum or minimum.

Comment: So, do you think it would answer the question if I just write my solution as: the local minima is (x, y) = (1, 5) ? I don't think there is a local maximum for this function.

Comment: You are probably supposed to not just list the extreme values but also provide proof that these are all of them. Hence, show your work of finding all critical points by setting the gradient equal to zero and then checking each of them for being a minimum or maximum.

Comment: @Only_me As a teacher I would insist that a solution contains a justification of why the other critical points don't produce (local) extrema. The final answer statement can probably ignore the list of saddle points if, somewhere along the line, you explain why they are saddle points. At least that's how I would grade this exercise.

Comment: Thanks Christoph and Jyrki. It's practice for a skills test I have to do prior to being admitted into a finance class, so I don't want to screw it up and not get into the class. They've given zero indication about the weight of each question (in terms of marks and how much time is allocated to each one).